# Run a command for each item in jq array

Tags: bash, jq

This is how my input file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "ConfigType": "ABC",
    "Prop1": 3,
    "Prop2": 30
  },
  {
    "ConfigType": "XYZ",
    "Prop3": "Hello",
    "Prop4": "World",
    "Prop5": "Application"
  }
]
```

I need to prepare insert statement for each item.

This is how my jq command looks like which gives me each item.

```
cat app-cnfg.json |  jq -r ".[]"
```

How do I execute `aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item <<array's element>>`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can pipe to `xargs`:

```bash
jq -c '.[]' app-cnfg.json \
    | xargs -L 1 aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item
```

The `-c` option to jq makes sure each element is on a single line, and the `-L 1` option to `xargs` makes sure that the command is called once per item.

If you wanted to avoid potential problems with trailing whitespace (which would make `args` treat the following line as continuation of the current one), you can get your objects zero byte separated (requires jq 1.7 or newer):

```bash
jq -c --raw-output0 '.[]' app-cnfg.json \
    | xargs -0 -n1 aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item
```

The `--raw-output0` option behaves like `-r`, but with NUL instead of newlines.

`xargs -0 -n1` expects zero byte delimited input and runs the command for each argument once.

---

For jq versions older than 1.7:

```bash
jq -j '.[] | tostring + "\u0000"' app-cnfg.json \
    | xargs -0 -n1 aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item
```

The `-j` option suppresses newlines from jq, `tostring` stringifies the objects and `+ "\u0000"` appends a zero byte.

Comment: `-L` is an interesting choice -- granted, `jq` should never emit a line that ends with whitespace (when not in raw-string mode), but if it *did*, that would be treated as a continuation as I understand it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's right, checking to see if I can get nul byte delimited output from jq...

Comment: You can; it's a little tricky. See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1271 for discussion -- `-j` suppresses the newlines, so you can add NULs via your expressions. `jq -j '.[] | (. + "\u0000")'`, to summarize (perhaps filtering them out from the data, if being suitably cautious).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Updated.

Comment: @BenjaminW. If I want to execute multiple commands like `echo` and then `aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item` on the same item, how do I do that?

Comment: You could write a shell function that takes the item as its argument, something like `myfunc () { echo "$1"; aws ... "$1"; }` and then call it like `| xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'myfunc "$1"' _ {}` (untested), or pipe to `while read -r -d '' item; do echo "$item"; aws ... "$item"; done` (untested)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks. I will test it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the filter to extract each element of the JSON array and feed it to an array in `bash` and iterate over its content later. Assuming you have `bash` 4.0 or greater, you can use `mapfile` command as

```
mapfile -t configArr < <(jq -c '.[]'  < app-cnfg.json)
```

and now we loop over the array, to run the command for each config item,

```
for config in "${configArr[@]}"; do
    aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item "$config"
done
```

(or) use a more efficient way to read from an input data stream using a `while` loop and the `read` command (works on `bash` versions that don't support `mapfile` or `readarray`)

```
while IFS= read -r config; do
    aws dynamodb put-item --table-name "xxx" --item "$config"
done< <(jq -c '.[]' < app-cnfg.json)
```